# Emacs indentation of comments in shell mode

Tags: emacs, indentation

Emacs default indentation of comments in **sh-mode** (after M-x `indent-region`)

```
# command --with --many --options \
    #         --after --backslah
```

How do I do this ?

```
# command --with --many --options \
#         --after --backslah
```

BTW with pipe all is OK (as I would expect)

```
# command --with -options |
#     command2 --after --pipe
```

To reproduce, type

```
command --with --many --options \
        --after --backslash
```

(notice how Emacs correctly indents the second line), then select these lines and `M-x` `comment-region` (works fine), then `M-x` `indent-region`

Answer (score 1):

Docstring of the user option `sh-indent-comment` states

> How a comment line is to be indented.
>
> nil means leave it as it is;
> t  means indent it as a normal line, aligning it to previous non-blank non-comment line;
> a number means align to that column, e.g. 0 means
> first column.

According to this, we can expect disabling this user option to result in the asked behavior. Namely:

```el
(setq sh-indent-comment nil)
```

But that doesn't seem to work as expected. Hence, I suggest to `M-x report-emacs-bug` for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with `sh-smie--looking-back-at-continuation-p`, which considers escaped newlines in comments to be continuations.

As a workaround, adding a check for comment syntax seems to do the trick

```
(define-advice sh-smie--looking-back-at-continuation-p (:around (orig-fn) "ignore-comment")
  (unless (nth 4 (syntax-ppss (and (not (bobp)) (bolp) (1- (point)))))
    (funcall orig-fn)))
```